# JQuery Autocomplete searching for term and its abbreviation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Using JQuery's UI autocomplete AND working with a terrible database schema is possible to search for a beginning of a term and it's abbreviation?

Let's assume I have the following churches in my database:

```
St Ignatius
St Mary of Sacred Heart
Saint Joseph
Saint Peter the Apostle
St Peter First Lutheran Church
```

How can a user type *Saint* and it return both *Saint* and *St*

I thought of this simple SQL UNION:

```
SELECT School_Name FROM mi_firstyear_advisors WHERE (School_Name LIKE '%Sain%')
UNION
SELECT School_Name FROM mi_firstyear_advisors WHERE (School_Name LIKE 'St %');
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: WHERE School_Name LIKE '%Sain%' OR School_Name LIKE 'St %' no?

Comment: does the query get the job done?

Comment: It does not. One is matched and returned but not both.

Answer (score 0):

In sql Use like that

Use CHARINDEX()

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(max)
Begin
SELECT School_Name FROM mi_firstyear_advisors WHERE CHARINDEX(@Name,School_Name)
End
```

Hope Its works !!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
switch($term){
        // If any variant of 'saint' is entered, search for any variant of 'saint'
        case (preg_match('/st .*/', $term) ? true : false):
        case (preg_match('/st\..*/', $term) ? true : false):
        case (preg_match('/sai.*/', $term) ? true : false):
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT School_Name FROM mi_firstyear_advisors WHERE School_Name LIKE ":term" OR School_Name LIKE "st %" OR School_Name LIKE "st. %" OR School_Name LIKE "%saint%"');
        break;

        // else just look for the given term
        default:
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT School_Name FROM mi_firstyear_advisors WHERE School_Name LIKE :term');
    }
```